Embedding of modules and annihilation by maximal ideal
Let $(R,\mathfrak m, k)$ be a Noetherian local domain of dimension $1$. Let $x\in \mathfrak m$ be such that $\mathfrak m^{n+1}=x\mathfrak m^n$. Let $Y$ be a finitely generated torsion-free $R$-module and $X$ be a finitely generated $R/xR$-module such that $Y/xY$ embeds in $X$. If $n\ge 2$ is an integer such that $\mathfrak m^n X=0$, then is $\mathfrak m^{n-1}Y/x\mathfrak m^{n-2}Y$ annihilated by $\mathfrak m$?
My thoughts: I can see this is true if $n=2$: An injective $R$-linear map $f: Y/xY\to X$ restricts to $\mathfrak m Y/xY$  and the image is contained in $\mathfrak m X$, which then by hypothesis, is annihilated by $\mathfrak m$. Since the restriction of an injective map is injective, we conclude that $\mathfrak m Y/xY$ is also annihilated by $\mathfrak m$.
I do not know how to extend this to higher $n>2$.
Please help

If $Y$ is torsion free, how can $\mathfrak{m}^n Y$ be zero?

@Mohan: should've been $X$ ... fixed now

Consider about the infiniteness of ascending ideal chain $(x^i)$. Then it can make contradiction to the noether property of $R$
